# Renaming multiindex row from a look up dictionary with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, rename, multi-index

Given a multilevel row as shown in current presentation, I would like to rename the first level index based on information stored in a look up dictionary.

Presently, I have the idea of transpose the `df` and looping to the now `column` name. Thereafter, the suitable new columns name will be checked and rename based on the information stored in the dictionary (i.e.,str_dic).

However, I wonder whether there is more straight forward of doing this?

The drafted code is as below

```
import pandas as pd

def create_df (idx):
    df = pd.DataFrame ( {'A': [11, 21, 31],
                         'B': [12, 22, 32],
                         'C': [13, 23, 33]},
                        index=['ONE', 'TWO', 'THREE'] )

    df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product ( [['level1'], ['level2'], df.columns] )
    df = df.set_index ( [[f'idx_{idx}'] * len ( df )], append=True ).swaplevel ( 0 )
    # df = df.set_index ( [['temp_general'] * len ( df )], append=True ).swaplevel ( 0 )
    return df

#look up dict
str_g = ['idx_0', 'idx_1', 'idx_2', 'idx_3','idx_4']
str_h = ['E', 'b', 'c', 'd','e']
str_dic = {str_g [i]: str_h [i] for i in range ( len ( str_g ) )}

# create the df
all_df = [create_df ( idx ) for idx in range ( 0, len(str_h)-1)] # Delibarately minus one for worse case scenario
df = pd.concat ( all_df, axis=0 )

df=df.T
all_ls=list(df.columns.values.tolist())
for xss in all_ls:
    df=df.rename ( columns={xss: str_dic[xss[0]]}, level=1) #WIP
```

Current presentation

```
level1        
            level2        
                 A   B   C
idx_0 ONE       11  12  13
      TWO       21  22  23
      THREE     31  32  33
idx_1 ONE       11  12  13
      TWO       21  22  23
      THREE     31  32  33
idx_2 ONE       11  12  13
      TWO       21  22  23
      THREE     31  32  33
idx_3 ONE       11  12  13
      TWO       21  22  23
      THREE     31  32  33
```

Expected Output

```
            level1        
            level2        
                 A   B   C
a     ONE       11  12  13
      TWO       21  22  23
      THREE     31  32  33
b     ONE       11  12  13
      TWO       21  22  23
      THREE     31  32  33
c     ONE       11  12  13
      TWO       21  22  23
      THREE     31  32  33
d     ONE       11  12  13
      TWO       21  22  23
      THREE     31  32  33
```

#######################

Bonus:
Based on suggestion by [Anurag Dabas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68693905/6446053), how can we append another level on the highest level based on another look up dict.

Naively, I would proposed something like

```
df.index =  pd.MultiIndex.from_product ( [s1, df.index.get_level_values ( 0 ).unique (),
                                          df.index.get_level_values ( 1 ).unique ()] )
```

But it return an error

> ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 12 elements, new values
> have 48 elements

The failed proposed amended based on Anurag:

```
str_global=['typ1','typ1','typ2','typ2','typ3']
global_dic = {str_h [i]: str_global [i] for i in range ( len ( str_h ) )}
s1 = [global_dic.get ( x ) for x in df.index.get_level_values ( 0 ).unique ()]

df.index =  pd.MultiIndex.from_product ( [s1, df.index.get_level_values ( 0 ).unique (),
                                          df.index.get_level_values ( 1 ).unique ()] )
```

Expected output

```
                    A   B   C
typ1    E     ONE       11  12  13
              TWO       21  22  23
              THREE     31  32  33
typ1    b     ONE       11  12  13
              TWO       21  22  23
              THREE     31  32  33
 typ2   c     ONE       11  12  13
              TWO       21  22  23
              THREE     31  32  33
 typ2   d     ONE       11  12  13
              TWO       21  22  23
              THREE     31  32  33
```

Comment: Actually given code's output and current output is not same!

Comment: Your r spot on @Xitiz. Im currently try to make this thing work. Please note the `WIP`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let's try replacing keys of str_dic in 'level 0' index with their values by using list comprehension  then generate a MultiIndex by using `pd.MultiIndex.from_product()` and set that equal to the index of your dataframe by using `index` attribute::

```
s=[str_dic.get(x) for x in df.index.get_level_values(0).unique()]
df.index=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([s,df.index.get_level_values(1).unique()])
```

**Update:**

Since Now you have 4 unique level0 value and 3unique level0 index and 4 value in  s1 so `pd.MultiIndex.from_product()` create 48 pairs of MultiIndex so it is not useful in that case so use:

```
s1=[global_dic.get(x) for x in df.index.get_level_values(0)]
df=df.set_index(pd.Series(s1).values,append=True)
df.index=df.index.reorder_levels([2,0,1])
```

output of `df`:

```
                level1        
                level2        
                 A   B   C
E     ONE       11  12  13
      TWO       21  22  23
      THREE     31  32  33
b     ONE       11  12  13
      TWO       21  22  23
      THREE     31  32  33
c     ONE       11  12  13
      TWO       21  22  23
      THREE     31  32  33
d     ONE       11  12  13
      TWO       21  22  23
      THREE     31  32  33
```

Comment: @balandongiv learning from you guys and this awesome community...glad my solutions helped ...happy coding **:)**

Comment: Hi @Anurag, slightly greedy here but hope you dont mind. I would like to extend your suggestion to append another  level on top of existing level. Based on the logic of your proposal, I repeat the 2 lines,but, the compiler return an error. I have edit and add the current finding at the bottom of the post.